# JQuery validate doesnt validate multiselect option

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a jQuery validate plugin which works fine for the textboxes but for the select option, it doesnt show any validate messages.

Not sure as to whats going wrong.

HTML

```
 <select id="idselect" name="id="idselect"" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="1">A</option>
                <option value="2">B</option>
                <option value="3">C</option>

            </select>
```

JQuery

```
$.validator.addMethod("needsSelection", function (value, element) {
              var count = $(element).find('option:selected').length;

        return length > 0;
    });

    $('#myForm').validate({

        rules: {

            idselect: {needsSelection : true},

            agree: "required"
        },


        messages: {

            idselect: { needsSelection: "Select atleast one" },

            agree: ""
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {

            form.submit();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"it doesnt show any validate messages."*

It's not working because the value for your `name` attribute is screwy...

```
name="id="idselect""
```

Change it to `name="idselect"` and it shows the message:

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/tmuyu2r2/**

---

You also don't need your `submitHandler` option at all as your function, `form.submit()` is the same as the default.  In other words, there's no point in over-riding it here.

---

**EDIT**:

Not sure why you need a custom method for this.  If you just need to mandate at least one option is selected, then the very simple `required` method can easily handle that.

**Quote OP's Comments**:

*"in your fiddle, even if i select an item, it still shows the validate message"*

Finally, in order to force validation to occur immediately after a selection is made, you need to capture the `change` event and trigger the `.valid()` method on the multi-select element.

```
$("#idselect").on("change", function() {  // whenever a selection is made
    $(this).valid(); // force validation in order to remove any messages
});
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/bdw1nv9z/1/**

Comment: in your fiddle, even if i select an item, it still shows the validate message

Comment: @user2281858, that's a failure with the code in your custom method.  However, since you only need at least one selected, just use the `required` rule.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/tmuyu2r2/1/

Comment: not working with bootstrap class multiselect, try it out

Comment: @user2281858, we must force validation to occur in order to clear out the message.  I think it's a bug within the plugin when using a multi-select.  See edited answer and demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/bdw1nv9z/1/

Comment: the problem is it works only when i select an option once and then deselect it. Doesnt work when i click on the submit button.

Comment: on submit click the multiselect doesnt seem to work. However I modified your code a bit to force validate on button click `   $('#test').click(function () {
            $('#idselect').valid();
        }); ` now it works on multiple button clicks. can u give me some heads up on this? as in it works on double clicks and not on single clicks.

Comment: or do u suggest that i add a new question for this issue.

Comment: @user2281858, If you expect me to comment on changes to the jsFiddle, then show the modified jsFiddle.  However, I have no idea what you're seeing as the latest jsFiddle is working fine for me.  I de-select the item and get a message, I select an item and the message goes away.  I don't have to do any double-clicking:  http://jsfiddle.net/bdw1nv9z/2/

Comment: @user2281858, I solved your original issue with the bungled up `name` preventing any message, so please accept my answer for that.  Then you could open a new question for this event triggering issue.  Please be detailed and include your code as well as the modified jsFiddle so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60920/discussion-between-user2281858-and-sparky).

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753379/jquery-validate-for-multiselect-works-only-on-double-click) to the new question, do have a look

Answer (score -1):

You would need to add option tag in your select which has an empty value. Empty Validation on the dropdown cannot occur if there is no empty value tag.

```
<select id="idselect" name="id="idselect"" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
<option value="">Select An Option</option>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You are mistaken.  OP is not using a multi-select where `option` with an empty value is not needed.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/j1cmfhu4/

Comment: Sparky - If you don't specify a default blank option with empty value, you would always have the 1st option selected ( which in this case would be '1' ), which would defy the purpose of having 'required'. Think logically before marking down someone elses answer.

Comment: Try out the jsFiddle before making comments.  Clearly, the first item is not selected here, and the form is blocked when nothing is selected: http://jsfiddle.net/tmuyu2r2/1/