# jQuery validate for multiselect works only on double click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a rather strange issue. My validate message is triggered only when I double click on my button click. I think there are some known issues with Bootstrap multiselect and jQuery plugin.

Please suggest some workaround.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdw1nv9z/5/)

Here is the code.

```
<link href="../../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <form id="myform" action="" method="post">

 <select id="idselect" name="idselect" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="1">A</option>
     <option value="2">B</option>
     <option value="3">C</option>
 </select>

 <input id="test" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

 </form>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('.multiselect').multiselect();


        $("#myform").validate({
            rules: {
                idselect: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                idselect: {
                    required: "Select atleast one"
                }
            }   
        });

        $('#test').click(function () {
            $("#idselect").valid(); // when i do this based on a suggestion from my previous question, i can at least make it work with a double click. else it wont just work.

        });

    });  
</script>
```

I am not sure how to get the bootstrap environment into fiddle. Let me know how can I be more clear with the question. The issue is simple - when I double click I see the validate message else it won't just show up. There are texboxes which work fine. The problem is with `multiselect`

Comment: I don't understand why you're using the `click` event from the `submit` button.  That was **not** the suggestion from your first question.  Since you want the message to clear when selecting a option, you need to bind to the `change` event **of the `select`, not the `button`**.

Comment: Please learn how to use jsFiddle and add the proper bootstrap resources to this one I started constructing for you. See "external resources" in the left hand panel. http://jsfiddle.net/bdw1nv9z/2/

Comment: add the fiddle to the question, http://jsfiddle.net/bdw1nv9z/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the multi-select plugin gives your original `select` a `display:none` and the jQuery Validate plugin will ignore all hidden elements by default, you'll need to disable that feature.

I simply added the `ignore` option to jQuery Validate, where `[]` as the parameter tells this plugin to ignore nothing.

```
$("myform").validate({
    // rules & options
    ignore: [],
    ....
```

Also, as per your previous question and [current jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdw1nv9z/5/), continue using the `change` event handler on the `select`, rather than the `click` handler on your button.  *(As discussed previously, this is needed because there seems to be an issue with the plugin where selecting items does not fire validation.)*

```
$("#idselect").on("change", function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/bdw1nv9z/8/**